# Hibernate Spring Integration Error: No Hibernate Session bound to thread

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a problem when integrate Hibernate and Spring. When I run the program, I will get `No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here`

I checked the forum, but most of them to do with transaction manager or missing context:component-scan. But I have it.

```
package com.cmpt.project.persistence;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class WarehouseDao {


    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public WarehouseDao (SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    public Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

And this is my configuration file spring-hibernate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />    

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cmpt.project.persistence"/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_demo"></property>
        <property name="username" value="username"></property>
        <property name="password" value="password"></property>
        <property name="initialSize" value="5"></property>
        <property name="maxActive" value="10"></property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="packagesToScan"
            value="com.cmpt.project.model">
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor">
    </bean> -->
</beans>
```

Here is my main

```
package com.cmpt.project.app;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.cmpt.project.model.Customer;
import com.cmpt.project.persistence.WarehouseDao;

public class ProjectDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-hibernate.xml");
        WarehouseDao dao = ctx.getBean("warehouseDao", WarehouseDao.class);

        Session session = dao.currentSession();
    }

}
```

As shown above, I didn't even update the database. I couldn't even get the session object. Please help, thank you.

Comment: YOu have to add a transaction manager and do proper transaction setup. Spring uses this information so it knows when to start a transaction and thus obtain a session.

Comment: You need to have the `@Transactional` annotation decorating the Hibernate DAO implementation classes.

Comment: I added @Transactional in my WarehouseDao class, and setup <bean id="transactionManager"class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean> But the same problem still occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the hibernate property:

```
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
```

to bound session to thread.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem. Thank you very much. May I ask why does it work? And why it couldn't work before? None of the text book and tutorial video mentions this setting.

Comment: Also, I plan to use multi-thread to update TABLEs. Can it interfere with multiple threads?

Comment: Using this, you're binding Hibernate Session to the current thread, so if you have multiples threads, each one has his own session. Take care about transaction management to keep consistence of your data, and you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. So Session Factory is a singleton created with configuration, and it spawns multiple session with multi-thread?